# Find unused constants in files iOS

Tags: ios, variables, automation, cocoapods

We had a requirement to convert a existing functionality to a separate pod, on this process we had to use existing projects constants file into the pod project,but not all the constants in the file are used in the POD project.Hence in the pod project, there are lot of unused #define constants.

How can I easily identify them, instead of doing it manually?

Comment: This might help if you can get it working https://github.com/dspinellis/cscout . Depending on the size of the task you might be better served sucking it up and going manually.

Answer (score 0):

You could do a project-wide text search for each (Shift+Command+F) or comment them all out and see where the build breaks.